# Proper preposition for "segregation"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, prepositions

Can the preposition 'between' be used to modify 'segregation'?

The context is a social-science research paper.

"...the most critical and crucial cause of the residential segregation between socioeconomic groups."

I incline towards the rule that the proper preposition for segregation is (always?) 'of.'

Thanks!

Comment: I would favor "of" in the above context.  It's hard to predict what may be appropriate in other cases without seeing them, though.

Comment: **1** *I incline towards the rule.* There are no "rules"; there is only guidance or suggestions. In your case, there is no sentence and there is not enough context to say what might be most appropriate. *"...the ... cause of the residential segregation of ... groups."* and *"...the ... cause of the residential segregation between ... groups."* are used in separate contexts.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I cut the sentence off to protect the author's privacy, and figured the context was more obvious than it apparently was. Should read: "X is...the most critical and crucial cause of the residential segregation between socioeconomic groups." I suppose my question is whether 'between' can ever be correct, and per Greybeard, it can.

Comment: 'the barrier between' . . . . . 'the segregation of'.

Comment: The relationship of the two noun concepts 'segregation' and 'the groups' is a genitive concept and is expressed in English as 'the segregation of the groups'. 'Of' here is not really a preposition, it is an expressed genitive. What is 'between' the groups . . . . is a barrier and in that case the preposition is locative.